# I have uploaded application with core data and I want to replace new core data without migration. Does apple allows it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to replace core data and want to delete old core data. Does Apple allows it to delete old core data. Is there any chance to reject app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple won't care, but your users might. If there is data that your users might be sorry to lose, you should make every effort to migrate it or give an option to export it when they upgrade.

If you're only using core data to cache downloaded values, then there's no problem with this at all. In fact, deleting the old store would be necessary to prevent the app crashing on upgrade, since it wouldn't be able to migrate from the existing store. The best place to do this is in the core data setup code when you receive an error - the boilerplate comments guide you toward this.

Comment: Thanks
We are using core data temporary. I hope user never mind about that because we refreshing old data using web services. Thanks again.

Comment: You'll be fine then - in fact, if you're changing the model, you'll _have_ to delete the old store. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are no problems doing that.
For example, you can check app's version in the AppDelegate:

```
- (void)clearCacheIfNeeded;
{
    NSString *savedVersion = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"currentVersion"];

    NSString *currentVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

    if (![savedVersion isEqualToString:currentVersion]) {
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *cachesDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:cachesDirectory error:NULL];
        NSEnumerator *e = [contents objectEnumerator];
        NSString *filename;
        while ((filename = [e nextObject])) {
            NSLog(@"file name: %@", filename);
            [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[cachesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] error:NULL];
        }
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:currentVersion forKey:@"currentVersion"];
    }

}
```